# Ahoy gem created mutually exclusive migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, ahoy

I tried to learn new stuff and use Ahoy gem for my private project. While doing research online, I encountered one repo with Rails 4.2 and Ahoy 1.6 and one thing struck me. Then I started googling and it seems like it's not a single repo issue only.

```rb
class CreateVisits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :visits, id: false do |t|
      t.uuid :id, default: nil, primary_key: true
(...)
```

rest of code omitted for readability

Am I missing something, or are those mutually exclusive lines? (not to mention primary key being nil by default?)

I ran almost the same migration locally (without Ahoy gem, with changed table name), and I got nicely-looking db/schema.rb (at first glance - no errors yet), but of course when I try create new object, I hit `ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint` error

In my opinion, I'd have write something like this to make it work, or am I missing something really important here that blocks me from persisting an object in DB?

```rb
class CreateVisits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :visits do |t|
      t.uuid :id, primary_key: true
(...)
```

Comment: What kind of database are you connecting to?

Comment: Same situation happen on PG and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this thing was not related to this Gem, but to other Dev running migration outside Rails migrations and not letting anyone know. This created some confusion between environments.